# I created a new tag for [arduino-c++] (this is igniting as opposed to burnination)

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-wiki

I created a new tag [arduino-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino-c%2b%2b) recently.

I've noticed that a significant number of questions tagged with the standard [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is tagged in combination with [arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino) and the answers from the realm of standard C++ mostly won't be a good fit for it.

Arduino has its own standard library, which is very different from the C++ standard library.

Also these kind of questions would be quickly downvoted (and are actually), because the C++ folks can't see the relevance of posted code examples.

---

Here's what I proposed for the user guidance and tag wiki info so far:

> Arduino C++ is a specific dialect of C++ primarily lacking some capabilities from the C++ standard library
>
> Use this tag to ask about Arduino-C++ specific problems. Don't use the C++ flag in conjunction.
>
> ---
>
> The Arduino standard library functions and classes are significantly different from the C++ standard library functions and classes.
>
> Note that there's also an Arduino dedicated Q&A site available in the stack exchange network: [**Arduino**](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/).

---

Please support me in re-tagging the questions with the current combination of [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino) tagged questions, if the code examples don't have any relevance for [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) basics/standards (I'll certainly not providing a retag editing spree, unless some followers would commit themselves and there's a greater consensus, this will be helpful).

Also help in improving the tag wiki information please.

---

I have no idea why this question receives so many negative response ATM of writing.

The people who are actually asked for support or disagreement should be experienced with the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag realm, where those Arduino-specific questions are usually not received as well (no matter if the [arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino) tag was added or not).

The C++ standard of course mentions features from the C++ standard library, that the *Arduino Standard* doesn't cover.

It would be a good thing if the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag won't be spilled with such specialized questions, but retag these with a more specialized context.

Comment: You know what igniting usually leads to? Burnination!

Comment: @JohnDvorak I love well energy balanced motors like the [Wankel Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wankel_engine). Also did your car explode or burnt down right away, when you turned on the ignition recently?

Comment: How would this tag be distinct from [tag:arduino]? How often would it be appropriate for a question on SO to be tagged with one but not the other?

Comment: I see the problem: arduino is a hardware platform **and** a programming environment **and** a language. Problem is, no noob will understand this new tag. maybe we just should accept the trinary usage of that tag and let it be. Personally, I remove the C and C++ tags from arduino questions (but are typically wrongly tagged, not just C++). The only problem is: the syntax highlighting of code does not wok. But that would be easy to fix.

Comment: @Olaf:  That sounds counterproductive.  Questions about Arduino here are *already* in the context of a programming environment.  The language is the tag that you seem to be removing for what appears to be almost no reason.

Comment: @Makoto: I have no idea if you know the Arduino environment at all. From your comment, I'd say you don't. Arduino is **not** C and **not** C++. So these tags are in fact blatantly wrong. What I recommend is to just accept the "Arduino" tag as language tag for automatic syntax highlighting of code-snippets instead of adding another tag which most likely will not be understood by askers anyway.

Comment: @Olaf:  I'm only giving you my opinion based in the similar circumstance of Processing and Java (in its early days).  It isn't like I don't *completely* understand Processing questions; I just understand enough to know, "Perhaps I shouldn't assume things."  I maintain that removing the language is counterproductive though; unless the question was *solely* about its IDE and had nothing to do with code, then *perhaps*.  We also have [arduino.se] for hobbyists to congregate to.

Comment: @Olaf I've used Arduino, and you're wrong. The language is *literally* C++, with a preprocessor that includes some headers and adds a main loop. Unless of course you're doing some of the Arduino/Processing stuff, in which case you write java (I think). Which is another point in favor of keeping a language tag.

Comment: @mbrig:  Hi!  Thanks for demonstrating up my point. ;)

Comment: @Makoto: Well, I know C, C++ and Arduino well enough to know what I'm writing. So maybe we have different starting point from here.

Comment: @mbrig: Please provide a reference to where the C standard allows for **two** different entry points into the application program (for instance). There are other issue, too. Most of them are more or less informal in that you shall not use C++ features which will generate a lot of overhead. Additionally, Arduino provides some libraries which are not aprt of the C++ standard either. For the rest: see the question. I just don't see we need another tag, the rest is correct.

Comment: @Olaf Are you aware of what the Arduino IDE is doing when you write setup() and loop()? It simply tacks on (via a preprocessing step) a main that handles it. Completely C++ standard compliant (not C standard though, because that's a very different thing). And libraries that aren't part of the c++ standard don't make a language not c++ either. Boost isn't in the c++ standard, but if I make an IDE that includes boost by default, I'm not suddenly writing a different language.

Comment: Same thing wrt features with high overhead. Zero difference from writing embedded c++ (or c) for a PIC or whatever.

Comment: @mbrig: I am aware about all this, possibly more than others defending the positions "Arduino is C" "Arduino is C++" and "C is C++ is C". And please read (and comprehend) **all** of my comment, not just particular parts out of context; thank you. I'll leave it at this, it is obvious it does not get anywhere.

Comment: @Olaf Please enlighten me then, how something that compiles with a completely bog-standard gcc/g++ compiler is not c++.

Comment: Let's discuss, why these kind of questions aren't so well received here in their majority please. Sure, arduino C++ is based on C++ and C++ preprocessor syntax and features. Also the C++ standard well refers to some features of the C++ standard library, that aren't covered with the [tag:arduino-c++] stuff. What's wrong with trying to give a valve to exhaust that wrongly tagged stuff?

Comment: To quote the Arduino people's FAQ: "the Arduino language is merely a set of C/C++ functions that can be called from your code"

Comment: @Olaf 5.1.2.1.1 "In a freestanding environment (in which C program execution may take place without any benefit of an operating system), the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined. Any library facilities available to a freestanding program, other than the minimal set required by clause 4, are implementation-defined."

Comment: @Vality: 1) We are talking about C++, not C! If you now claim "Arduino is C", we are done here so very much. In case you confuse C and C++: different languages. Whoever disagrees has **obviously** no idea about at least one of them. 2) Assuming this is simlar to the C++ wording: Count the number of functions for an Arduino program. Last time tere were **two**. In my understanding " the name and type of **the function** called at program startup" is clear about a **singular** function. Feel free to file a defect report about a typo.

Comment: @Olaf No, I was responding to :Please provide a reference to where the C standard allows for two different entry points into the application program (for instance)

Comment: Although this is Meta, **comments are *still* not for extended discussion**. If you have an opinion to share, then please put it in the answer box below ↓

Answer (score 12):

What questions related to Arduino would be on-topic without programming, really?  My personal expectation would be that the [arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino) tag would accompany the language that it's programmed in to allow for us to get the best context possible.  [A cursory Google](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/programming-languages-can-use-arduino/) shows that there's more than one language out there that can be used with Arduino.

If we kept that going, then the convention would be to munge the language with the tag as well.  I'm not sure I like that trend, and I'm not convinced that we really need to go this route.

Any C++ users who come to the realization that this is an Arduino question and they may *not* have the full context of it would know to back down.  This is what happens with us Java users any time we see the [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing) tag attached to a [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)-tagged question.  Any that don't...well, I can't say they weren't warned.

(Oh, I nearly forgot that [Arduino Processing](https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Processing) was a thing.  Well, that's *another* tag...)

Comment: Well, the problem is "Arduino" is a hardware platform, an IDE and a (C++ derived) language. The first and last are definitively relevant for questions., the second depends on the question. The problem I have with a new tag is more: the users of that platform are mostly hobbyists, who don't get those differences ("it's all Arduino"). Also retagging the current questions would be a sysiphos job, so I#d say: just remove the C and C++ tags and let it be "Arduino"..

Comment: @Olaf: I don't necessarily agree with that stance.  There's no value in removing the language from the tag.  I get that hobbyists may not "get it" (like they don't with Processing), but it isn't like a C++ enthusiast is a *complete* neophyte when it comes to anything with Arduino.  My advice holds; if one doesn't know, then it's best just to back down.

Comment: No offence, but from your profile, I don't see you have any (or relevant) experience in embedded development. There is a major difference between hose small bare-metal embedded systems and PC or even small embedded Linux-boxes. I'm still to meet a **good** PC-level C++ programmer being able to write reasonable PIC/AVR/HC08/etc. code fwithout major adoption. Such people use the featuzres of the language (and that's what I expect). Arduino, etc. is more like C programming style (invoking methods does not change this, it si just syntactic sugar!).

Comment: So yes, the C++ tag is missguiding. And the C tag is absolutely wrong. I had enough fruitless discussions about both, most of them instantly showed a major lack of understanding what C and C++ actually constitutes. For that reason I will leave this discussion. I want to have a fun weekend.

Comment: @Olaf: I've stated my position in arguing this stance.  I feel any further discussion on this merit would not be beneficial to either of us.  We clearly understand each other's positions.  Perhaps you would be best to codify yours in an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree. The C++ Tag is about the C++ language, not about the C++ standard library. If I understand correctly, the Arduino uses the [Wiring Framework](http://wiring.org.co/reference/) so it seems more sensible to use the C++ tag in conjunction with a tag for the Wiring Framework to describe Arduino code.

Comment: There are C++ standard constructs (not related to the library) you must not use on Arduino. Also the entry into the application is non-standard. Finally, a normal PC-level C++ programmer will have a very tough time writing more than simple Arduino programs (but then most of the Arduinos are used for something a wire+switch would suffice anyway). So no, the C++ tags is not good. I'd say the "Arduino" tag alone is sufficient, though.

Comment: @Vality: FYI: The C++ tag is for the C++ *standard*. And the C++ standard includes the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

There is `https://arduino.stackexchange.com/` , Arduino related stuff should go there